# Solve matrix equation with scalar value

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, minimize

I have two square matrices, A and B and wish to find the scalar value, s, which minimizes the below equation:

||A-sB||

where || is the 2-norm. How can I efficiently code this in python with numpy or scipy?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [scipy.optimize.minimize](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html#scipy.optimize.minimize): first define your objective function, which I called `f`, then `minimize` requires an initial guess `x0` and additional parameters of the function you want to minimize:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def f(x, A, B):
    return np.linalg.norm(A-x*B, ord=2)

n = 3

A = np.ones((n,n))
B = np.arange(n**2).reshape(n,n)

minimize(f, x0=1, args=(A, B))
      fun: 1.5845110835227028
 hess_inv: array([[0.00838895]])
      jac: array([-4.47034836e-08])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nfev: 24
      nit: 5
     njev: 8
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([0.1844041])
```

Minimize will return a sort of optimization report, in particular you care about the `x` value, which you can access as a dictionary `minimize(f, x0=1, args=(A, B))['x']`.